# very basic probability question

Tags: probability

I choose one ball from each of three boxes. the first contains one white and one black, the second one black and one red, and the third one red and one white. Find the probability I draw at least one red.

I have done this using the tree diagram, and I got 3/4 - is there a shorter method using combinatorics or alike?

Comment: Did you mean you choose _three_ balls, one from each box?

Comment: yes sorry I did

Answer (score 1):

If you first work out the probability of not drawing **any** reds at all, then you get:$$P_{no-reds}=1\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$$Then just subtract this from $1$ to get the probability of drawing at least one red.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it in this way.

for the first box $\frac{0}{2}$ because there is no red in there

for the second box $\frac{1}{2}$

for the third box $\frac{1}{2}$

$\cup$ one or two = probability of one red ball + probability of two red balls 
$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{2} = .75$